# How to invalidate data in Next.js's app directory when not using fetch?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

### Background - Before Next.js 13

Prior to the introduction of the app directory into Next, it was possible to return a `revalidate` option from `getStaticProps`:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {...},
    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  }
}
```

If a request came in after that revalidation window, `getStaticProps` would be recalled on a serverless function, performing any functionality along with it - typically fetching some data.

This would work with *any* data fetching approach - it could be `fetch`, but it could also be straight to Firebase, or with Axios, etc.

### Next.js 13 onwards

In Next 13, `fetch` now has "special" meaning:

```
const revalidatedData = await fetch(`https://...`, {
  next: { revalidate: 10 },
});
```

### Question

In Next 13, how can I replicate the ISR model but with any data fetching approach?

For example, what would the following look like in Next 13?

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const user = await axios.get('/user?ID=12345');

  return {
    props: { user },
    revalidate: 10,
  }
}
```

Axios is just an example of async data fetching. It could be any non-fetch approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using [`fetch`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch), you can still revalidate using [Route Segment Config Options](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) and React's [`cache`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#react-cache-function) function as they say on the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-third-party-libraries):

> In cases where you're using a third-party library that doesn't support or expose [`fetch`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch) (for example, a database, CMS, or ORM client), you can configure the caching and revalidating behavior of those requests using the  [Route Segment Config Options](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) and React's [`cache`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#react-cache-function) function.

> In the example below, the revalidate option is set to 3600, meaning the data will be cached and revalidated at most every hour.
> The React `cache` function is used to [memoize](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#request-memoization) data requests:

```js
import { cache } from 'react'
 
export const revalidate = 3600 // revalidate the data at most every hour
 
export const getItem = cache(async (id) => {
  const item = await db.item.findUnique({ id })
  return item
})
```

> Although the `getItem` function is called twice, only one query will be made to the database.

```js
// app/item/[id]/layout.js

import { getItem } from '@/utils/get-item'
 
export default async function Layout({ params: { id } }) {
  const item = await getItem(id)
  // ...
}
```

```js
// app/item/[id]/page.js

import { getItem } from '@/utils/get-item'
 
export default async function Page({ params: { id } }) {
  const item = await getItem(id)
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that section in the beta doc. It wasn't mentioned in the upgrade guides